# custom Horizontal listview not support imageview

Tags: android

how to load dynamic images in custom listview i follow this tutorial to show listview in horizontal http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34 but the problem is this example HorizontialListView   not support image view  only text will be show if i replace image view  with Listview image wil be show   code is work fine if i replace HorizontalListView  with Listvew    both image and textview will show

```
            public class fifthstep extends Activity {
               private HorizontalListView listview;
private HorizontalListView listview;

CategoryListAdapter2 cla;


static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();

String CategoryAPI;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listviewdemo);
                listview = (HorizontalListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview2);

    cla = new CategoryListAdapter2(fifthstep.this);






               CategoryAPI = Utils.CategoryAPI;


    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 
  15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(CategoryAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }


            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 

            //    JSONObject category = 
        object.getJSONObject("Category");


            Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("rank")));
                Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));
                Category_image.add(object.getString("url"));
                Log.d("Category name", Category_name.get(i));
                listview.setAdapter(cla);


            }




                       public class CategoryListAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public CategoryListAdapter2(Activity act) {
    this.activity = act;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(act);
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return fifthstep.Category_ID.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    holder.txtText.setText(fifthstep.Category_name.get(position));

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(fifthstep.Category_image.get(position),
            activity, holder.imgThumb);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtText;
    ImageView imgThumb;
}



      }







                 public class HorizontalListView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> {

public boolean mAlwaysOverrideTouch = true;
protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
private int mLeftViewIndex = -1;
private int mRightViewIndex = 0;
protected int mCurrentX;
protected int mNextX;
private int mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int mDisplayOffset = 0;
protected Scroller mScroller;
private GestureDetector mGesture;
private Queue<View> mRemovedViewQueue = new LinkedList<View>();
private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClicked;
private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClicked;
private boolean mDataChanged = false;


public HorizontalListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
}

private synchronized void initView() {
    mLeftViewIndex = -1;
    mRightViewIndex = 0;
    mDisplayOffset = 0;
    mCurrentX = 0;
    mNextX = 0;
    mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
    mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
}

@Override
public void setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
    mOnItemSelected = listener;
}

@Override
public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener){
    mOnItemClicked = listener;
}

@Override
public void setOnItemLongClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
    mOnItemLongClicked = listener;
}

private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
            mDataChanged = true;
        }
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        reset();
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

};

@Override
public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
    return mAdapter;
}

@Override
public View getSelectedView() {
    //TODO: implement
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    if(mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
    }
    mAdapter = adapter;
    mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
    reset();
}

private synchronized void reset(){
    initView();
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    //TODO: implement
}

private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, int viewPos) {
    LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    if(params == null) {
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    }

    addViewInLayout(child, viewPos, params, true);
    child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
}



@Override
protected synchronized void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    if(mAdapter == null){
        return;
    }

    if(mDataChanged){
        int oldCurrentX = mCurrentX;
        initView();
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        mNextX = oldCurrentX;
        mDataChanged = false;
    }

    if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()){
        int scrollx = mScroller.getCurrX();
        mNextX = scrollx;
    }

    if(mNextX <= 0){
        mNextX = 0;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    }
    if(mNextX >= mMaxX) {
        mNextX = mMaxX;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    }

    int dx = mCurrentX - mNextX;

    removeNonVisibleItems(dx);
    fillList(dx);
    positionItems(dx);

    mCurrentX = mNextX;

    if(!mScroller.isFinished()){
        post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestLayout();
            }
        });

    }
}

private void fillList(final int dx) {
    int edge = 0;
    View child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    if(child != null) {
        edge = child.getRight();
    }
    fillListRight(edge, dx);

    edge = 0;
    child = getChildAt(0);
    if(child != null) {
        edge = child.getLeft();
    }
    fillListLeft(edge, dx);


}

private void fillListRight(int rightEdge, final int dx) {
    while(rightEdge + dx < getWidth() && mRightViewIndex < mAdapter.getCount()) {

        View child = mAdapter.getView(mRightViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
        addAndMeasureChild(child, -1);
        rightEdge += child.getMeasuredWidth();

        if(mRightViewIndex == mAdapter.getCount()-1) {
            mMaxX = mCurrentX + rightEdge - getWidth();
        }

        if (mMaxX < 0) {
            mMaxX = 0;
        }
        mRightViewIndex++;
    }

}

private void fillListLeft(int leftEdge, final int dx) {
    while(leftEdge + dx > 0 && mLeftViewIndex >= 0) {
        View child = mAdapter.getView(mLeftViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
        addAndMeasureChild(child, 0);
        leftEdge -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
        mLeftViewIndex--;
        mDisplayOffset -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
    }
}

private void removeNonVisibleItems(final int dx) {
    View child = getChildAt(0);
    while(child != null && child.getRight() + dx <= 0) {
        mDisplayOffset += child.getMeasuredWidth();
        mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
        removeViewInLayout(child);
        mLeftViewIndex++;
        child = getChildAt(0);

    }

    child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    while(child != null && child.getLeft() + dx >= getWidth()) {
        mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
        removeViewInLayout(child);
        mRightViewIndex--;
        child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    }
}

private void positionItems(final int dx) {
    if(getChildCount() > 0){
        mDisplayOffset += dx;
        int left = mDisplayOffset;
        for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            child.layout(left, 0, left + childWidth, 
      child.getMeasuredHeight());
            left += childWidth + child.getPaddingRight();
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void scrollTo(int x) {
    mScroller.startScroll(mNextX, 0, x - mNextX, 0);
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    handled |= mGesture.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return handled;
}

protected boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
    synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
        mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, (int)-velocityX, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
    }
    requestLayout();

    return true;
}

protected boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    return true;
}

private OnGestureListener mOnGesture = new 
     GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return HorizontalListView.this.onDown(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        return HorizontalListView.this.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, 
   velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
            mNextX += (int)distanceX;
        }
        requestLayout();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (isEventWithinView(e, child)) {
                if(mOnItemClicked != null){

 mOnItemClicked.onItemClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, 
   mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                }
                if(mOnItemSelected != null){

 mOnItemSelected.onItemSelected(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + 
   i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                }
                break;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (isEventWithinView(e, child)) {
                if (mOnItemLongClicked != null) {

 mOnItemLongClicked.onItemLongClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 
    + i, mAdapter.getItemId(mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i));
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    private boolean isEventWithinView(MotionEvent e, View child) {
        Rect viewRect = new Rect();
        int[] childPosition = new int[2];
        child.getLocationOnScreen(childPosition);
        int left = childPosition[0];
        int right = left + child.getWidth();
        int top = childPosition[1];
        int bottom = top + child.getHeight();
        viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
        return viewRect.contains((int) e.getRawX(), (int) e.getRawY());
    }
};



       }
```

public class HorizontalListView extends AdapterView {

```
public boolean mAlwaysOverrideTouch = true;
protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
private int mLeftViewIndex = -1;
private int mRightViewIndex = 0;
protected int mCurrentX;
protected int mNextX;
private int mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int mDisplayOffset = 0;
protected Scroller mScroller;
private GestureDetector mGesture;
private Queue<View> mRemovedViewQueue = new LinkedList<View>();
private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClicked;
private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClicked;
private boolean mDataChanged = false;
private boolean mMeasureHeightForVisibleOnly = true;


public HorizontalListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
}

private synchronized void initView() {
    mLeftViewIndex = -1;
    mRightViewIndex = 0;
    mDisplayOffset = 0;
    mCurrentX = 0;
    mNextX = 0;
    mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
    mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
}

@Override
public void setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
    mOnItemSelected = listener;
}

@Override
public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener){
    mOnItemClicked = listener;
}

 @Override
 public void setOnItemLongClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
    mOnItemLongClicked = listener;
 }

 private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
            mDataChanged = true;
        }
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        reset();
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

};

 @Override
 public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
    return mAdapter;
 }

 @Override
 public View getSelectedView() {
    //TODO: implement
    return null;
 }

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    if(mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
    }
    mAdapter = adapter;
    mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
    reset();
 }

  /**
  * @param visibleOnly - If set to true, then height is calculated
  * only using visible views. If set to false then height is
 * calculated using _all_ views in adapter. Default is true.
* Be very careful when passing false, as this may result in
```

* significant performance hit for larger number of views.
    */
    public void setHeightMeasureMode(boolean visibleOnly) {
        if(mMeasureHeightForVisibleOnly != visibleOnly) {
            mMeasureHeightForVisibleOnly = visibleOnly;
            requestLayout();
        }
     }

```
 private synchronized void reset(){
    initView();
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    requestLayout();
}

 @Override
 public void setSelection(int position) {
    //TODO: implement
 }

private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, int viewPos) {
    LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    if(params == null) {
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    }

    addViewInLayout(child, viewPos, params, true);
    child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
 }

 @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    if(MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        int height = 0;

        if(mMeasureHeightForVisibleOnly) {
            int childCount = getChildCount();
            for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                View v = getChildAt(i);
                v.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                if(v.getMeasuredHeight() > height) {
                    height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
            }
        } else {

            /* Traverses _all_ views! Bypasses view recycler! */

            HashMap<Integer, View> mRecycler = new HashMap<Integer, View>();
            int childCount = getAdapter().getCount();
            for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                int type = getAdapter().getItemViewType(i);
                View convertView = mRecycler.get(type);
                View v = getAdapter().getView(i, convertView, this);
                mRecycler.put(type, v);

                v.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                if(v.getMeasuredHeight() > height) {
                    height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
            }
        }

        if(MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            int maxHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            if(maxHeight < height) {
                height = maxHeight;
            }
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), height);
    }
}

 @Override
 protected synchronized void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top,
                                                      int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    if(mAdapter == null){
        return;
    }

    if(mDataChanged){
        int oldCurrentX = mCurrentX;
        initView();
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        mNextX = oldCurrentX;
        mDataChanged = false;
    }

    if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()){
        int scrollx = mScroller.getCurrX();
        mNextX = scrollx;
    }

    if(mNextX <= 0){
        mNextX = 0;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    }
    if(mNextX >= mMaxX) {
        mNextX = mMaxX;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    }

    int dx = mCurrentX - mNextX;

    removeNonVisibleItems(dx);
    fillList(dx);
    positionItems(dx);

    mCurrentX = mNextX;

    if(!mScroller.isFinished()){
        post(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                requestLayout();
            }
        });

    }
 }

 private void fillList(final int dx) {
    int edge = 0;
    View child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    if(child != null) {
        edge = child.getRight();
    }
    fillListRight(edge, dx);

    edge = 0;
    child = getChildAt(0);
    if(child != null) {
        edge = child.getLeft();
    }
    fillListLeft(edge, dx);


 }

 private void fillListRight(int rightEdge, final int dx) {
    while(rightEdge + dx < getWidth() && mRightViewIndex < mAdapter.getCount()) {

        View child = mAdapter.getView(mRightViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
        addAndMeasureChild(child, -1);
        rightEdge += child.getMeasuredWidth();

        if(mRightViewIndex == mAdapter.getCount()-1) {
            mMaxX = mCurrentX + rightEdge - getWidth();
        }

        if (mMaxX < 0) {
            mMaxX = 0;
        }
        mRightViewIndex++;
    }

}

 private void fillListLeft(int leftEdge, final int dx) {
    while(leftEdge + dx > 0 && mLeftViewIndex >= 0) {
        View child = mAdapter.getView(mLeftViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
        addAndMeasureChild(child, 0);
        leftEdge -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
        mLeftViewIndex--;
        mDisplayOffset -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
    }
}

private void removeNonVisibleItems(final int dx) {
    View child = getChildAt(0);
    while(child != null && child.getRight() + dx <= 0) {
        mDisplayOffset += child.getMeasuredWidth();
        mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
        removeViewInLayout(child);
        mLeftViewIndex++;
        child = getChildAt(0);

    }

    child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    while(child != null && child.getLeft() + dx >= getWidth()) {
        mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
        removeViewInLayout(child);
        mRightViewIndex--;
        child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    }
}

 private void positionItems(final int dx) {
    if(getChildCount() > 0){
        mDisplayOffset += dx;
        int left = mDisplayOffset;
        for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            child.layout(left, 0, left + childWidth, child.getMeasuredHeight());
            left += childWidth;
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void scrollTo(int x) {
    mScroller.startScroll(mNextX, 0, x - mNextX, 0);
    requestLayout();
}

 @Override
 public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
     boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    handled |= mGesture.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return handled;
 }

 protected boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
    synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
        mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, (int)-velocityX, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
    }
    requestLayout();

    return true;
 }

  protected boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    return true;
 }

 private OnGestureListener mOnGesture = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return HorizontalListView.this.onDown(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        return HorizontalListView.this.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
            mNextX += (int)distanceX;
        }
        requestLayout();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        Rect viewRect = new Rect();
        for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            int left = child.getLeft();
            int right = child.getRight();
            int top = child.getTop();
            int bottom = child.getBottom();
            viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
            if(viewRect.contains((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY())){
                if(mOnItemClicked != null){
                    mOnItemClicked.onItemClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, 
 mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                }
                if(mOnItemSelected != null){
                    mOnItemSelected.onItemSelected(HorizontalListView.this, child, 
    mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                }
                break;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Rect viewRect = new Rect();
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            int left = child.getLeft();
            int right = child.getRight();
            int top = child.getTop();
            int bottom = child.getBottom();
            viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
            if (viewRect.contains((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY())) {
                if (mOnItemLongClicked != null) {
                    mOnItemLongClicked.onItemLongClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, 
     mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId(mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i));
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }

   };



   }
```

Comment: code is working fine if i replace  HorizontalListView  with Listview
HorizontalListView  only show text not image  Listview show both things

Comment: if i comments this line 
imageLoader.DisplayImage(fifthstep.Category_image.get(position),
    activity, holder.imgThumb);
default icon wil show  problem is Horizontal listview not support dynamic images

Comment: if i change  HorizontalListView with simple ListView  both image and textwil show

Comment: i get solution please can any one post this solution to others please